# How can I implement a OneToMany association with a separate link table?

Tags: doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I'm implementing a new application on top of an existing database. The existing database is being used by a mobile application and because the mobile app is being developed by a different team I am not allowed to change the structure of existing tables.

The existing database has a user table and for my own application's users I created my own table and Doctrine entity called PortalUser (table portal_user).

The PortalUser entity is going to have a OneToMany association called $children which refers to the existing User entity. In other words each PortalUser has zero or more child User entities.

The most natural way to implement this is to have something like this (simplified):

User (the existing entity):

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var PortalUser
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PortalUser", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;
}
```

PortalUser entity:

```
class PortalUser
{
    /**
     * @var  int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var array
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    protected $children;
}
```

This will create a new column "parent_id" in the existing user table which isn't allowed. So would it be possible to get a separate link table with parent_id and child_id columns, equivalent to a regular ManyToMany link table? And if so what annotations would result in such a structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is embarrassing. Turns out it's in the Doctrine documentation:

> A unidirectional one-to-many association can be mapped through a join
>   table. From Doctrine’s point of view, it is simply mapped as a
>   unidirectional many-to-many whereby a unique constraint on one of the
>   join columns enforces the one-to-many cardinality.

[Doctrine manual](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html?highlight=onetoone)